# NSLayoutConstraint throwing exception "is not a key in the views dictionary"

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to use autolayout programatically and facing some issues. My code is simple. I have a view and I am trying to add label to that using NSLayoutConstraint as below

```
 UILabel* downloadLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
 [self.leftView addSubview:downloadLabel];
 downloadLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
 [downloadLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  NSDictionary *downloadlabelDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(downloadLabel);
  NSArray *downloadLabelConstraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[dowloadLabel(40)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:downloadlabelDict];
  NSArray *downloadLabelConstraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[dowloadLabel(200)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:downloadlabelDict];


  [downloadLabel addConstraints:downloadLabelConstraint_H];
  [downloadLabel addConstraints:downloadLabelConstraint_V];
```

When I run the application it throws exception when trying to create first NSLayoutConstraint.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
dowloadLabel is not a key in the views dictionary.V:[dowloadLabel(40)]
```

Comment: You mistyped downloadLabel as dowloadLabel. It's right there in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant `downloadLabel` and not `dowloadLabel` in the two lines where you build your constraints?

Comment: Thanks, I hate strings for this particular reason. Its very easy to mistype and overlook it in error message. Probably should use #define everywhere. Compilers should show this as suggestions when throwing exceptions. "Do you mean downloadLabel?"